# How to make an Actor spawn on mouse hover and destroy itself after seconds?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to spawn tiles in 3D world. 
I already made the BP for the mouse click spawning, but I want to add a "preview" (on mouse hover) of where it would be placed on click.

I tried using the same technique for the preview. But I'm not sure what event I should use.

I tried using Mouse Right Click Event and it worked, but that's not what I'm aiming for, because that way I'm missing the "mouse hover" part.

I tired using Event Tick, but it seems to cause a problem with the destroy function. And instead of spawning the tiles for 0.2 secs and destroying them, it just continuously spawns them without destroying.

[image: EventTickBP]
[image: WhatHappensOnPlay]

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong , the mesh to hover with a light material should always show whenever the spawning function(which you have not made) is used/clicked(as per requirement of game).

Then the Mouse Right Click Event should be used to spawn the actual mesh and to add a little good effect whenever the mouse is clicked the hover mesh should dissapear for a delay of 1 second and the reappear.

So it should go as follows:
1- Spawn function should create a hollow mesh underneath your mouse . It should have no relation with the tick function.
2- Mouse clicked event should spawn the actual mesh. It should have no relation with tick except look for your break result when needed using a condition handled by the Mouse click or spawn function.The spawning class itself should have a destroy function after begin play .

Try to use tick function less and less and only use when needed using a condition . This will make you learn more .Tick runs every frame and is dangerous. Learn to tame it with conditions.

Comment: I have made the "spawning on click" function, I just didn't include a screenshot of it. I am aware that the Tick Event isn't working for me in this case and that's why my question is "Is there another way of doing that?". Thank you.

Comment: You said its not working for you because you are missing the hover part. Why cant it be a hidden mesh .